# Find xpath nearest element

Tags: html, css, xpath

I need to define an xpath before an element on the page. I have a string(FIO) that I can find using xpath and I need to bind to it. I don't understand how to do it.

My xpath witch i can find on page:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]//div[1]/span[contains(., '"+FIO+"')]
```

look at screenshot, i need find string 1, it have xpath:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/a
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY59N.png)

string with my param(FIO) 2, have xpath:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[1]/span
```

and i  shortened it and inserted a variable:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]//div[1]/span[contains(., '"+FIO+"')]
```

how i can get xpath to element 2 with binding at element 1 ? maybe following sibling ?

sorry, i can't copy the code correctly, only like this:

```
                    </div>
</div>
        <ul>
                        <li>
<div class="structure2__item1">
    <div class="structure2__item2" style="">
         <a class="structure2__position" href=https://**>
               "String 2"
            </a>
            <div class="structure2__name" style="">
                  <span>String_FIO</span>
            </div>                                 
                </div>
</div>
</li>
                        <li>
```

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and posting code in images is  not recommended.

Comment: Add HTML as text not image. Also do not use Absolute XPaths. 1) They are not reliable. 2) Looks just awful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//div[child::span[contains(text(), "String_FIO")]]/preceding-sibling::a
```

This would help fetch the a tag from the span.

(From next time - please look out for the standards mentioned in the comments.)

Comment: thanks, it works! it is necessary to deal with these anchors, while it is unclear to me